# "error return without exception set" for python list

Tags: python, list

What does "Error return without exception set" commonly mean? I am trying to call a Python method that should return a list.

```
 for facet in dispPart.FacetedBodies:
     #Tag
     facet_tag2=thisFctBody.Tag

     #calling this method returns an "error return without exception set" 
     face_list=facet.GetFaces()
```

[This is what I've found on it so far](https://docs.plm.automation.siemens.com/data_services/resources/nx/10/nx_api/en_US/custom/nxopen_python_ref/NXOpen.Facet.FacetedBody.html?highlight=getfaces#nxopen-facet-facetedbody-getfaces)

Comment: show the full traceback please, I assume this is a `SystemError`?

Answer (score 2):

You shoud tell what third party Python module you are using  - this error message implies there is something wrong in that code, not yours. (ok, from your link, it is "NXOpen Python API")

Specifically, the third party module, interfacing with the Python C API returned an incorrect result, reporting an exception should have been raised, but did not tell Python which exception is that.

It is possible that there is something incorrect in your input data that, if fixed, could allow for normal return of the desired call - nonetheless it is buggy as it is.

One thing you might try is to call some other method on your `facet` object to check if, for example, it is not empty.